# Sintax error _grokparsefailure in logstash

Tags: pattern-matching, logstash, logstash-grok

Hello i have the follow example lines to match with grok but it only generate this  _grokparsefailure error:

> OSSEC - RULEID: "1484654377"; RULEID: "5402"; RULELEVEL: "3"; RULEGROUP: "syslog,sudo"; RULECOMMENT: "Successful sudo to ROOT executed"; DSTUSER: "root"; SRCIP: "None"; HOSTNAME: "elk-stack-2"; LOCATION: "/var/log/auth.log"; EVENT: "[INIT]Jan 17 09:59:36 elk-stack-2 sudo: root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su[END]";

My grok conf is:

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "OSSEC - RULEID: \"%{NUMBER:timestamp}\"; RULEID: \"${NUMBER:ruleid}\"; RULELEVEL: \"${NUMBER:rulelevel}\"; RULEGROUP: \"${GREEDYDATA:rulegroup}\"; RULECOMMENT: \"${DATA:rulecomment}\"; DSTUSER: \"${NOTSPACE:dstuser}\"; SRCIP: \"${NOTSPACE:srcip}\"; HOSTNAME: \"${NOTSPACE:hostname}\"; LOCATION: \"${NOTSPACE:location}\"; EVENT: \"[INIT]${DATA:event}[END]\";"
        }
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, this is the full line: `OSSEC - RULEID: "1484654377"; RULEID: "5402"; RULELEVEL: "3"; RULEGROUP: "syslog,sudo"; RULECOMMENT: "Successful sudo to ROOT executed"; DSTUSER: "root"; SRCIP: "None"; HOSTNAME: "elk-stack-2"; LOCATION: "/var/log/auth.log"; EVENT: "[INIT]Jan 17 09:59:36 elk-stack-2 sudo:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su[END]";
`

Comment: Don't use comments for updating Questions; just edit the Question and add your details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confused the syntax: you used `$` instead of `%` in many cases above (with `%{...}`). Also, the `[` outside the character class must be escaped to match a literal `[` symbols. I also suggest to use `DATA` instead of `GREEDYDATA` with the `rulegroup` field.

Use

```
OSSEC - RULEID: \"%{NUMBER:timestamp}\"; RULEID: \"%{NUMBER:ruleid}\"; RULELEVEL: \"%{NUMBER:rulelevel}\"; RULEGROUP: \"%{DATA:rulegroup}\"; RULECOMMENT: \"%{DATA:rulecomment}\"; DSTUSER: \"%{NOTSPACE:dstuser}\"; SRCIP: \"%{NOTSPACE:srcip}\"; HOSTNAME: \"%{NOTSPACE:hostname}\"; LOCATION: \"%{NOTSPACE:location}\"; EVENT: \"\[INIT\]%{DATA:event}\[END\]\";
```

Also, you may replace all spaces with `\s+` to streamline matching if the whitespace may differ.

Comment: Worked perfectly!! Very thanks for you time to resolve this problem. and thank you again for confused the $ instead of %. But, what the real diference in between DATA and GREEDYDATA ? thank you!

Comment: `DATA` (=`.*?`) matches lazily, matching as few chars as possible, and `GREEDYDATA` grabs as many chars from the current location to the right as possible  (=`.*`).